# How to get selected option value in edit mode (codeigniter)

Tags: forms, codeigniter, html-select

i have form with options, when i want to edit it, the value goes back like in create function. what i want to ask is how to get the value i've selected in edit function?

here is my model

```
  //get data by id
public function get_data($id = FALSE){
    if($id === FALSE){
    $query = $this->db->get('forms');
    return $query->result_array();
    }

    $query = $this->db->get_where('forms', array('id' => $id));
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

my controller

```
// get form by id
   public function get_data_id($id = NULL){


    $data['title'] = 'Update Data';

    $data['statuses'] = $this->status_model->get_status();        
    $data['form'] = $this->form_model->get_data($id);       

    if(empty($data['form'])){
        show_404();
    }

    $this->load->view('globals/header');
    $this->load->view('globals/navigation');
    $this->load->view('forms/edit_data', $data);
    $this->load->view('globals/footer'); 

}
```

my edit view

```
<?= form_open('forms/updating_data')?>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $form['id']?>" >
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="<?= $form['name']?>">        
        </div>           
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="stat">Status</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="stat">
                <?php foreach($statuses as $stat):?>
                    <option value="<?= $stat['status']?>"><?= $stat['status']?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">Update</button>
        </form>
```

can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the data that you want to edit (the `$form` array) also contains the `status`.

And then you need to add an `if` statement to your select box, which sets the selected value to the `status` that is in the `$form` array, like this:

```
<select class="form-control" name="stat">
    <?php foreach($statuses as $stat):?>
        <option value="<?= $stat['status']?>"
            <?php if ($stat['status'] == $form['status']) : ?> selected<?php endif; ?>
        >
            <?= $stat['status']?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: its help me to identify the selected value, but how to show the selected value in the first place? i mean without scrolling down and select it again..

Comment: This code should select/show the value in the select box that was chosen the last time the form was saved. If it's not selecting the value, then `$form['status']` doesn't match any of the options in `$statuses`. What are the values of `$statuses` and `$form['status']`?